# How to filter an array in rxjs data stream?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to display reviews in song-details.component.ts based on songId. I have code something in review.service.ts which filters the data based on songId. But the code doesn't work. It still displays all the songs reviews under each song. Please guide me

The following is song-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SongListService} from '../song-list.service';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-song-list',
  templateUrl: './song-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./song-list.component.css']
})
export class SongListComponent implements OnInit {

  public songList: Array<any>;  
  searchTerm: string;

   constructor(private songListService: SongListService) {}

   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.songListService.retrieveAllSongs().subscribe((data: any) => this.songList = data);}
         }
```

The following is song-details.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {SongListService} from '../song-list.service';
import {ReviewService} from '../review.service';   


@Component({
  selector: 'app-song-details',
  templateUrl: './song-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./song-details.component.css']
})
export class SongDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

   songs: any;
   reviews: any;

  
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private songListService: SongListService
    private reviewService: ReviewService) { };

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params.get('id'))
       this.songListService.retrieveSongsById(params.get('id')).subscribe(s =>{
          console.log(s);
          this.songs = s;
      })  

      });

      this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params.get('id'))
      this.reviewService.retrieveReviewsBySongId(params.get('id')).subscribe(r =>{
        console.log(r);
        this.reviews = r;
    })
  })
```

The following is review.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { tap} from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ReviewService {


  private headers: HttpHeaders;
  

  private accessPointUrl: string = 'https://localhost:44355/api/reviews';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
  }


  public retrieveReviews(){
    return this.http.get(this.accessPointUrl,  {headers: this.headers});
  }

  public retrieveReviewsBySongId(songId){
    return this.http.get(this.accessPointUrl,  {headers: this.headers})
                .pipe(tap((data:any) => data.filter((d:any)=> d.songID == songId)));
  }
```

[Reviews API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToK28.png)

Comment: Why subscribe to `paramMap` twice? I'd put both code blocks in the same handler. Can you verify that your api returns the correct reviews? In the webbrowser - F12 - Network tab - filter for XHR (ajax calls) and post a screenshot of the response you get from your api

Comment: the first paramMap retrieves song details and the second one retrieve reviews. I have added the screenshot of the response. Pls take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

The `tap` operator will only preform an action ("do this and that"), but will not transform or do anything in the context of changing or manipulating the stream.
Replace the `tap` operator with `map` operator.
With map you will be able to transform the data and map and return it as the filtered array instead of the original.

for further reading: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map

```
public retrieveReviewsBySongId(songId){
    return this.http.get(this.accessPointUrl,  {headers: this.headers})
                .pipe(map((data:any) => data.filter((d:any)=> d.songID == songId)));
  }
```

Comment: Great, you can mark the answer as accepted answer if it solves. Another thing, I saw you're doing assignments of values to the component inside subscribe, you might want to read about the `async` pipe in angular, it will simplify your code.

Answer (score -1):

I really don't like the `pipe` and `tap` commands. I know they're all over the internet, but I'd suggest trying to avoid them...

I created a StackBlitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8ikirg?file=src/app/app.module.ts

---

src/app/entities/review.ts

```
export class Review {
  id: number;
  songID: number;
  username: string;
  reviews: string;
  ratings: number;
}
```

src/app/services/review.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Inject, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Review } from "../entities/review";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class ReviewService {
  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    @Inject("BASE_URL") private baseUrl: string
  ) {}

  public retrieveReviews() {
    return this.httpClient.get<Review[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/api/reviews`, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      }
    }).toPromise();
  }

  public retrieveReviewsBySongId(songId: number) {
    return this.retrieveReviews()
      .then((revs) => revs.filter((rev) => rev.songID === songId));
  }
}
```

Added the `BASE_URL` provider in the `main.ts`

```
import './polyfills';
import { enableProdMode, StaticProvider } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

let providers: StaticProvider[] = [{
  provide: 'BASE_URL',
  useValue: 'https://localhost:44355'
}];

platformBrowserDynamic(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(ref => {
  // Ensure Angular destroys itself on hot reloads.
  if (window['ngRef']) {
    window['ngRef'].destroy();
  }
  window['ngRef'] = ref;

  // Otherwise, log the boot error
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

The place where I fetch the reviews (app.component.ts)

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private reviewService: ReviewService) {}

  reviews: Review[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.reviewService.retrieveReviewsBySongId(1).then(reviews => {
      this.reviews = reviews;
    });
  }
}
```

Displaying the reviews (app.component.html)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>User</td>
        <td>SongID</td>
        <td>Ratings</td>
        <td>Reviews</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let review of reviews">
        <td>{{ review.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ review.username }}</td>
        <td>{{ review.songID }}</td>
        <td>{{ review.ratings }}</td>
        <td>{{ review.reviews }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I suspect things are going wrong in your `review.service`, so I'd suggest modifying it to the one I posted.